# How i get the list of module before load modules?

Tags: prism

I want to use moduleinfor as a menu, so I must get the list of the module before load modules.I would check the module if it should be loaded, but I don't know when and how to get the list of the module before load modules.
Please show me some help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking about this all wrong.  You tell Prism what modules you have. So you should already know this information. If you must do it this way, you could ask for the IModuleCatalog and iterate through the Modules. Keep in mind that the ModuleInfo objects do not implement INPC and will not send change notifications.